# Google Map marker text

Tags: google-maps, marker

I have found this icon: http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=mm&chs=60x102&chco=ffffff,70a3c1,70a3c1&ext=.png

I'm wondering if it's possible to place text on this icon. Basically what I'm looking for is an icon with a dynamic color and text. A simple PHP script that dynamically generates an icon based on a images and text would also be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can create image from png ([using PHP GD](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) )

```
 $yourimage = imagecreatefrompng($originalImage);
```

Add in your html page this tag

```
 <img src="test_icon.php?text=yourtext">
```

and the add the text  you need
this way using test_icon.php

**test_icon.php**

```
<?php

   header("Content-type: image/png");

   $yourOrigImage = "group_icon.png";
   if(file_exists($yourOrigImage)) {
      $newImage = imagecreatefrompng($yourOrigImage);
      imagesavealpha($newImage, true); // this for keep the png's transparency  important
      if(!$newImage) {
        die("im is null");
    }
    $black = imagecolorallocate($newImage, 0, 0, 0);
    $width = 36; // the width of the image
    $height = 36; // the height of the image
    $font = 4; // font size
    $text = $_GET['text']; // text
    $leftTextPos = 4;
    $outputImage = "group_icon_".$text.".png";
    imagestring($newImage, $font, $leftTextPos, 9, $text, $black);
    imagepng($newImage, $outputImage, 0);
    imagedestroy($newImage);
}

?>
```

Comment: Nope, just a blank page.

Comment: Have you the  GD component active on your server?

Comment: How you render the image?. I think probably you need save the image for future use in google maps

Comment: Realtime, not yet using it in a map.

Comment: If you sohw the code i can evaluate it otherwise i can't imagine what are you doing...

Comment: I have update the answer. i hope this could be useful

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. The third party [MarkerWithLabel](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/docs/examples.html) library.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfwt956h/3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

  var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map,
    icon: "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=mm&chs=60x102&chco=ffffff,70a3c1,70a3c1&ext=.png",
    labelContent: "A",
    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 90),
    labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
    labelInBackground: false
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
.labels {
  color: black;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

2. Add a label to the native [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#marker_labels)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfwt956h/2/)

**code snippet:**:

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map,
    icon: "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=mm&chs=60x102&chco=ffffff,70a3c1,70a3c1&ext=.png",
    label: "A"
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```